# Calling a function defined inside jQuery ready from outside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery

My aspx page:-

```
  <script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      //lots of other code here....
      function showMessage(){
        $("#msgDiv").dialog({
                        modal: true,
                        buttons: {
                                  Ok: function() {
                                          $(this).dialog('close');
                                      }
                        },
                        resizable: true,
                        show: "explode",
                        position: "center",
                        closeOnEscape: true,
                        draggable: false
                      });
      }
    });
   </script>
```

Another aspx pop up page which is triggered from the above page

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.opener.document.getElementById("msgDiv").innerHTML = <%=MessageToShow%>; //works very well for me.
    window.opener.document.showMessage(); // I am unable to access it like this?
    window.close();

</script>
```

Basically I want to call `showMessage()` from the pop up window. I also have other logics to perform in both pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, what you want to do, can't be done.  So, what exactly can we do?

I think the simpliest think would be to move `showMessage` outside of the `ready` function, and just call it from within.

Now, if it really must be defined within that function, make it a named function:

```
  function calledonready()
  {
      /// stuff
      function showMessage(){ 
      /// stuff
      }
   }

$(document).ready(calledonready);

window.opener.document.calledonready.showMessage();
```

Comment: This is not working for me. Though I can access `calledonready` like this `window.opener.window.calledonready`. But when I access it like this `window.opener.window.calledonready.showMessage()`, it says `TypeError: Object calledonready has no method 'showMessage'`

Comment: Is there going to be any problem with jquery ui dialog if I move showMessage() out of the ready function? If no, I have no other reason to keep it inside.

Answer (score 15):

Declare your function like this inside the  document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    window.showMessage = function() {
        //...
    };

});
```

Then you should be able to call it from the other document like this:

```
window.opener.showMessage();
```

And because it's in the global scope, you can call it from within the main document just by calling

```
showMessage();
```

Comment: I'm sure that, in this case I will have to call it by `window.opener.window.showMessage();` in the pop up window. +1 though. Now its already moved out and working, so don't want to modify it again unless there is any problem. Thanks very much.

Comment: You shouldn't need to double up the window reference. window.opener will return a reference to the window that opened the current one. The only reason window.opener.window works is because the window element contains a reference to itself (as window). If you don't believe me, try window.opener.window.window.window.showMessage() ;)

Comment: Just wanted to +1 this, since it would globalize the *`showMessage`* function.  I assume it would also be possible to attach it to the jquery namespace `jQuery.fn.showMessage=function(){...}`, which you could probably call like `jQuery.showMessage()` outside the ready.

Answer (score 3):

You can just declare `showMessage()` public by putting it directly under your `<script>` tag. Well that turns out as bad practice actually, but it would work.

The better solution should always be to use your own namespace. Declare an `object` where all of your application logic can take place.

```
<script>
var MyApp = {
    showMessage:   function(){
       // do something
    }
};
```

Later in your code you can access this object from everywhere with

```
MyApp.showMessage();
```

You can bring that pattern to an extend by using `closures`. A lot of smart people developed nice patterns for the `ecmascript` therefore. A good read like always is `Javascript: the good parts" by Douglas Crockford.

```
var MyApp = function(){
    var my_private_data = "version 1.0.0",
        foo             = "bar";

     return {
        getfoo          = function(){
             return(foo);
        },
        showMessage     = function(){
             // do something
        }
     };
};

var app = MyApp();

app.showMessage();
```

This is all about `private data` and `namespacing`. That way no other script on your side can possibly change any date you hold within your `closured` object. The idea can even taken much further by creating `inheritance` and `shared data` (semi protected), but I guess this is another story.

Comment: +1 Thanks a million ton for teaching this nice concept and best practice. Although I'm just moving out my `showMessage()`, as I'm not doing lots of javascript in my page, but I know that this is the best answer to the question.