# How to access a inner nested function from outside?

Tags: javascript

Here's a sample code of the situation that I'm stuck in:

```
    <script>
    var mod = (function(){
        var inn1;
        function innfunc(){

        }
    }()); //mod is self expression function
    </script>
```

Suppose that HTML includes this javascript code and I would like to open my Java console and call the `innfunc()` or the variable `inn1`, then what can I write?

perhaps something like: `mod.innfunc()`?

Comment: You can return innfunc, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/W76Z8/

Comment: I think this post might be helps you in this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402877/calling-a-function-defined-inside-jquery-ready-from-outside-of-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to expose a "public interface" by returning it from inside the function:

```
return {
    inn: inn1,
    innfunc: innfunc
}
```

Then you can access them using `mod.inn` and `mod.innfunc`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 var mod = function(){

    this.inn1 = "Hello";

    this.innfunc = function(){
      console.log('Here');
    }

  }; 
  var x = new mod();
  console.log(x.inn1);
  x.innfunc();
```

you can use this to make variables and methods public

Answer (score 0):

You have **executed an anonymous function** and assigned the result of that function to `mod`. **You no longer have access to that anonymous function or any of its properties**.

If you want to access any of its properties later, there are multiple ways to do this. One of them is:

**Return an object having properties which you need outside of this function**

```
var mod = (function() {
  var inn1 = 'somevalue';

  var innfunc = function() {
  };

  return {
    inn1: inn1,
    innfunc: innfunc
  };
}()); //mod is self expression function
```

Now, you can access it as `mod.innfunc()`

Answer (score 0):

+1 to what the others have said. I guess they beat me to it, haha.

I've added an example of stuff you can keep private within the function as well:

```
var mod = (function() {

    var publicText = 'Public!';
    var privateText = 'Private';

    var func1 = function() {
        console.log('hi');
    };

    var func2 = function() {
        console.log('there');
    };

    return {
        hi: func1,
        there: func2,
        publicText: publicText
    };
})();

mod.hi();
mod.there();

console.log(mod.publicText);

// This will fail, since the object.key privateText was never defined
console.log(mod.privateText);
```

Hope this helps!