# Use variable from Ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two files:

*example.html:*

```
<div class="my-div"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "example1.html",
        type: "get",
        success: function(response) {
            $(".my-div").html(response);
        }
    });

    $(document).on("click", "button", function() {
        console.log(alpha); // Should print "data", 
    });
});
</script>
```

*example1.html:*

```
<button></button>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("", {
        success: function(file, response) {
            const alpha = "data";
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

In *example.html*, I need `console.log(alpha)` to output "data". I make an Ajax request to `example1.html`, and update the contents of my div with the returned html. The constant `alpha` isn't useable until `new Dropzone()` succeeds. How can I make this code work?

Comment: My personal opinion, what you want to do is a pretty bad idea. Even if it would work, the variable alpha is scoped to the success callback, it is not global so the button would not be able to see it.

Comment: Thanks @epascarello. I understand your concerns, a better way to do this would probably be to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28478146/7304372) answer's suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to make your `alpha` variable global.

You declared your `alpha` variable inside success function so you can only use that variable inside it.

```
<button></button>
<script type="text/javascript">
const alpha; /* Init it here */

$(document).ready(function() {
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("", {
        success: function(file, response) {
            alpha = "data"; /* Assign the value here */
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Now you can access it as

```
$(document).on("click", "button", function() {
    console.log(alpha); // Should print "data", 
});
```

Comment: Alpha needs to be initiated as a variable to avoid the first error. Then after that, Alpha still returns undefined

Comment: And make sure that you define the variable outside any functions

Comment: I initiated and defined it only once. It's outside of any functions, at the top of a script tag. Basically like [this](https://i.imgur.com/3IXIUdT.png)

Comment: This should be working. What is the value of your response before you assign it to alpha?

Comment: And also, make sure that you already assign the value before you use it

Comment: *Facepalm*; response was never defined. Working now. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help :)